# mat-button-toggle-checked in mat-button-toggle-group if it is consecutive. Angular 7+

Tags: angular, angular-material

button should be selected only consecutive for e.g, if 8:00 selected and 8:15 is not selected then 8:30 should not selected.[please check more in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obAQN.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please go through all these links: [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [how to good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: And after: Read this: https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/examples

Comment: please check image attached for more specific.

Comment: finalSlotselectedValue = [1,2,3,4,5,6] // true
finalSlotselectedValue = [1,2,4,5,6] // false